# Trying to iterate an array of URL's in React?

Tags: reactjs, image, heroku

I am trying to create an image gallery using Heroku's new add:on 'simple-file-upload'. I've managed to get everything saved to the database and I can display 1 image at a time, but am having trouble creating the gallery now. I've set everything up how I think it should be, but when I `console.log(files)` I am not receiving the URL, but rather just the number `1` from the count. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here? Here is my code below:

```
import React from "react";
import SimpleFileUpload, { SimpleFileUploadProvider } from "../components/SimpleFileUpload"
import { useState } from 'react'
import "./styles.css"

const API_KEY = ''

let count = 0;

export default function About() {
  const [files, setFiles] = useState([]);
  console.log(files)
  //var Gallery = [];
  //Gallery.push(files);
  //console.log(files)

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>upload an image</h1>
      <SimpleFileUpload apiKey={API_KEY} onSuccess={() => setFiles([...files, `${++count}`])} />
      {!!files &&
        files.map(a => {
          return (
            <div
              key={a}
              style={{
                display: "flex",
                justifyContent: "space-between",
                marginTop: 5
              }}
            >
              <div>{a}</div>
              {/*
                 button to remove entries from the array, this should also make an API call to remove them from your server (unless the files are required for something like an audit).
                */}
              <button onClick={() => setFiles(files.filter(f => f !== a))}>
                Remove
              </button>
            </div>
          );
        })} 
        
        
      
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: You will need to update your onSuccess call back to provide a URL as a parameter, you can then replace your onSuccess function with `(url) => setFiles([...files, url])`

Comment: It works! Thanks again... greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `onSuccess` handler isn't accepting files. the `...files` in `() => setFiles([...files,` ${++count}`])` is the `files` from `const [files, setFiles] = useState([]);`, ie, `[]`, leaving you with `${++count}`, ie, `1`.

changing it to `files => setFiles([...files` ${++count}`])` should fix it---though i don't know what `onSuccess` does, so i can't say for sure.